# No puedo ver pdf en sistema en Red con DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

tengo un sistema hehco en laravel 5.7 y para hacer informes en PDF instale DOMPDF. Cuando lo miro en el servidor lo veo lo mas bien, el problema es cuando quiero verlo desde una máquina cliente, me muestra la página que no lo encuentra en el servidor (ERR_CONECTION_RESET). Cual puede ser el error? Tal vez sea de permisos, el resto del sistema funciona bien.
Desde ya muchas gracias, saludos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mosrtrar una imagen del error

Comment: Ahí puse una imagen, saludos

Comment: Viendo la imagen me Di cuenta el error, ésta solicitando al localhost y desde la pc cliente tiene que solicitar al ip del servidor. Tengo que cambiar el doc .vue el enlace. Perdonen las molestias